# How to put an image onto a 3d object

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I dont have a picture right now but I want to put an image over a sphere but I have no idea how, can any one show me how? thanks a plenty! :-)

Comment: This is explained in the manual. https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/image/workflow.html There are plenty tutorials on the internet. Search for "blender texture sphere". This was the first result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U